# After Android Studio update. Could not parse POM, Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

Hello I've been looking to other similar questions about this problem but none has helped me so far, after I updated to android studio to the new version 3.6.2 I have this error when I try to run any project.

Run info:

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:_internal_aapt2_binary'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
>        Required by:
>            project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:aapt2:3.6.2-6040484.
>   Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2/3.6.2-6040484/aapt2-3.6.2-6040484.pom
>   Content is not allowed in prolog.

Before the update the project was able to build now none of my projects build.
I tried invalidate cache and restart, I checked that I was not running in offline mode. still have the same failure. Any idea whay this could be and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the Error by going to my username and deleting .gradle, .AndroidStudio3.6 and .AndroidStudio3.5 folders. after I restarted android studio to download the folders again and resetting them. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

if you have problem with gradle 
change your android stadio version to 3.6.2  or lower

file>project Strcture> 
change to 3.6.2 and OK

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried but it still failing to build giving other erros. I fixed it by deleting the .Android and .Gradle and re started android studio to download the folders again and resetting them. thanks